# How to Create a JavaScript Array with a Range or Sequence

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way that I can possibly do `[200:204]` in JavaScript to generate this array `[200, 201, 202, 203]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
const range = (a, b) => Array(b-a).fill(a).map((v, i) => v + i);
```

And then use

```
const arr = range(200, 204);
```